# Sending COMMAND or CTRL key in nightwatch to close browser tab

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

Iam trying to close a tab on Chrome/IE browsers in Nightwatch
Its accepting all the keys other than CTRL in Windows or COMMAND in Mac.

```
loginPage.sendKeys("@login", [client.Keys.CONTROL, "w" ]);
```

All of the below work as expected

```
 loginPage.sendKeys("@login", [client.Keys.SHIFT, "w" ]);
 loginPage.sendKeys("@login", [client.Keys.ENTER, "w"]);
 loginPage.sendKeys("@login", [client.Keys.SEMICOLON, "w"]);
```

I can close the tab using `closeWindow` funtion, but it doesnt invoke the beforeunload event of browser close. I think its killing the Chrome/IE process instead of closing it.So i am looking for an alternate way to close the tab in nightwatch.

Comment: did you try to add `, browser.Keys.NULL` as last "key"? i.e. `loginPage.sendKeys("@login", [client.Keys.CONTROL, "w", browser.Keys.NULL ]);`

Comment: Its working in IE , but not in Chrome. Could be issue with the chrome driver?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that pressing CTRL+A works fine

```
client.keys([client.Keys.CONTROL, "a"]);
```

But not the CTRL+J or CTRL+W

```
client.keys([client.Keys.CONTROL, "j"]);
```

Another way of doing so is

```
client.keys(client.Keys.CONTROL, () => {
         client.keys('a'));
     });
```

But again CTRL+J or CTRL+W won't do the job.

Comment: I wouldn't say that nightwatch is retarded, as much as it tries to make you think so. I think it's an unfinished product. Why it's been released in its current state I have no idea. Function keys also don't work, like client.Keys.F12 and so on. switchWindow() completely ignores the string within it. I question the purpose of nightwatch's existence.

Comment: @Alichino you can always help in this kind of modules... it's released because it's stable for the majority of cases, only because you have some random case where things are not working... you don't have the right to judge others hard work, when you can write a custom command to solve your cases.

Comment: Suppose I release my own selenium wrapper that has only a handful of commands available, and is stable - what would be the point of that? Opening new windows tabs, navigating between and so on is BASIC functionality for Selenium. webdriverIO has it implemented and working fine, and is using JS. Not mentioning that by default nightwatch operates in async mode, which is unnecessary and overkill for a Selenium-based UI testing. Also, by your reasoning, I can write all (custom) commands myself, so again - what is the point of nightwatch? It's an unfinished product.